# Probability that graph with $6$ vertices and $5$ edges has a triangle.

Tags: probability, graph-theory

> How to calcultate a probability that a graph with $6$ vertices and $5$ edges has a triangle?

So we have ${15\choose 5}=3003$ (labeled) graphs and ${6\choose 3} =20$ possible triangles.

Let $m_i$ be a number of graphs with $i$-th triangle. Then $m_i= {12\choose 2}= 66$ and $m_{i,j} = 1$ if $\Delta _i$ and $\Delta _j$ have one common side, else it is $0$. Notice that $m_{i,j} = 1$ is $9$ times for each $i$. So $$m= 20\cdot 66 - {20\cdot 9\over 2} = 1230$$

So $$P = {1230\over 3003} \approx 0.41 $$

Is this correct and how to calculate this probability in general if we have $n$ vertices and $\varepsilon$ edges?

Comment: Isn't it ${15\choose 5}$ graphs instead of ${15\choose 6}$?  We choose $5$ of the $15$ edges in $K_6$.

Comment: Of course it is, thanks! @saulspatz

Comment: @Aqua: Yes, $1230/3003$ is correct for the case of $6$ vertices, $5$ edges.

Comment: What about some general idea? @quasi

Comment: $m_{i,j}$ is in general hard to calculate...

Comment: @Aqua: Define $f(n,e)$ as the number of labeled simple graphs with $n$ vertices, $e$ edges, and at least one triangle. What you want is a formula (possibly a summation) or a recursion for $f(n,e)$. My feeling is that it's hopeless. Assuming no answers are posted resolving the issue, what you might try is to do a few more cases with small values of $n,e$, or perhaps small values of $e$, leaving $n$ unknown, and see if the data matches some oeis sequence.

Comment: Vhat some good estimation/upper bound? @quasi

Comment: Estimates or fairly tight bounds are worthwhile targets, but still probably hard to achieve. It has the feel of a research topic rather than a problem which might yield a quick answer. My suggestion: Start with simulations to get a sense of potential estimates or bounds.

Comment: Sounds like this will be very hard.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118686/counting-triangle-free-graphs

Comment: @Aqua https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00528.pdf -- Minimising the number of triangular edges

Comment: @Aqua, here is a draft of small simulation library(igraph)

triangle <- graph_from_literal( A--B, B--C, C--A)
plot(triangle)


ntrials <- 1000
ntriangles <- numeric(ntrials)

for (i in (1:ntrials)) {
 g      <- erdos.renyi.game(n=6, p.or.m=5, type="gnm", directed=FALSE)
 iso    <- subgraph_isomorphisms(triangle, g)      
 motifs <- lapply(iso, function (x) { induced_subgraph(g, x) })
      ntriangles[i]  <- length(unique(motifs))
}
plot(g)
hist(ntriangles)

Comment: @Aqua, what is an application field for your question?

Answer (score 4):

For integers $n,e$ with $n \ge 1$ and $e\ge 0$, let $S=S(n,e)$ be the set of simple graphs on the labeled vertices $1,...,n$ having exactly $e$ edges.

- Let $E(n,e)$ be the expected number of triangles for a randomly chosen graph from $S$.

  Then we get
  $$E(n,e)={\large{\frac
  {
  \binom{n}{3}\binom{m-3}{e-3}
  }
  {
  \binom{m}{e}
  }}}
  $$
  where $m=\large{\binom{n}{2}}$.

  Let $T(n,e)$ be the number of graphs in $S$ having at least one triangle.

  A few partial results:
  $$
  T(n,3)=
  \frac
  {
  n(n-1)(n-2)
  }
  {6}
  \\[16pt]
  T(n,4)=
  \frac{
  n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n+2)
  }
  {12}
  \\[16pt]
  T(n,5)=
  \frac
  {
  n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n^3+n^2-10n-28)
  }
  {48}
  \\[16pt]
  T(n,6)=
  \frac
  {
  n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n^5-21n^3-56n^2+152n+620)
  }
  {288}
  \\[12pt]
  $$
  More generally, fixing $e\ge 3$, it's not hard to show that
  $$T(n,e)=\sum_{k=j}^{2e-3}a_k{\small{\binom{n}{k}}}$$
  where

  - $j$ is the least positive integer such that ${\large{\binom{j}{2}}} \ge e$.$\\[4pt]$

    Each $a_k$ is the number of simple graphs on the labeled vertices $1,...,k$ having exactly $e$ edges, at least one triangle, and no isolated vertices.$\\[14pt]$

  Noting that each $a_k$ is a positive integer constant (depending on $e$ and $k$, but independent of $n$), it follows that for all $e\ge 3$, we have $T(n,e)=\Theta(n^{2e-3})$.

Comment: Let $n=6$, $e=5$ then $m=15$ and $E(n=6,e=5)={\large{\frac
{
\binom{6}{3}\binom{12}{2}
}
{
\binom{15}{5}
}}}=\frac{20 \cdot 66}{3003}
$. One can see that the expected number of triangles $E(6, 5)$ is not integer. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Nick: The expected number of triangles is a kind of _average_, so there's no requirement for it to be an integer.

Comment: what is a method to write down the $a_k$ value?

Comment: @Nick: Other than a brute force count, I'm not sure.

Comment: I am looking on $T(n, e)$'s for brute force count, for instance, $3 \leq n \leq 5$, and $0 < e < 10$. Unfortunately, i can't see the relation between $T(n, e)$ and $T(n, e+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

I made a simulation. 
First, I created the `triangle` graph then generate the `100,000` random graphs with `n=6` vertices and `m=5` edges using the [Erdos-Renyi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model), and find the distribution of triangles.

The probability $P=0.40660 \approx 0.41$.

[image]

As one can see only two events were in the simulation: a) the random graph does not have a triangle, b) the random graph has one triangle. But in theory the graph $G(V, E)$ where $n=|V|=6$, $m=|E|=5$ can have two triangles with one common edge:

[image]

**The R code is below.**

```
library(igraph)

triangle <- graph_from_literal( A--B, B--C, C--A)

ntrials <- 100000
ntriangles <- numeric(ntrials)

for (i in (1:ntrials)) {
    g      <- erdos.renyi.game(n=6, p.or.m=5, type="gnm", directed=FALSE)
    iso    <- subgraph_isomorphisms(triangle, g)      
    motifs <- lapply(iso, function (x) { get.edgelist(induced_subgraph(g, x)) })
      ntriangles[i]  <- length(unique(motifs))
}

hist(ntriangles, freq=TRUE, labels = TRUE, breaks=3, col="red", xlim=c(0,2),
main="Triangle's distribution", xlab="Triangles")

two_triangles <- graph_from_literal( A--B, B--C, C--A, A -- D, D -- B, E, F)
plot(two_triangles)
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for posting the R code. It seems like it could be very useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by counting the labeled triangle-free graphs on $6$ vertices and $5$ edges. Let's classify them according to the cycles they contain.

**Case 1. No cycles.** An acyclic graph with $6$ vertices and $5$ edges is a tree. By Cayley's theorem, the number of labeled trees on $6$ vertices is
$$6^4=\boxed{1296}.$$

Otherwise, the graph must contain a cycle of length $4$ or $5$, since $3$-cycles are forbidden and we don't have enough edges for a $6$-cycle.

**Case 2. Cycle of length $5$.** The only possible unlabeled graph is $C_5+K_1$; the number of labelings is
$$\binom61\cdot\frac{4!}2=\boxed{72}.$$

**Case 3. Cycle of length $4$.** Here there are two possible unlabeled graphs.

**Case 3a.** $C_4+K_2$. The number of labelings is
$$\binom62\cdot\frac{3!}2=\boxed{45}.$$

**Case 3b.** The graph with degree sequence $3,2,2,2,1,0$ in which the vertex of degree $1$ is adjacent to the vertex with degree $3$. There are $6\cdot5\cdot4$ ways to label the vertices of degree $0$, $1$, and $3$, and then $3$ ways to label the vertex of degree $2$ which is not adjacent to the vertex of degree $3$, so the number of labelings is
$$6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3=\boxed{360}.$$

Thus the number of **triangle-free graphs** is
$$1296+72+45+360=1773;$$
the number of **graphs with triangles** is
$$\binom{15}5-1773=3003-1773=1230;$$
so the probability that a random graph with $6$ vertices and $5$ edges will contain a triangle is
$$\frac{1230}{3003}=\boxed{\frac{410}{1001}}\approx0.4096$$

which is the same answer you got.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there are $20$ possible triangles.  Having made a triangle, there are $12$ edges left, so each one accounts for ${12 \choose 2}=66$ graphs.  The cases where there are two triangles have been counted twice.  For those, you choose four vertices to be part of the triangles, then delete one of the six edges of the $K_4$, so there are ${6 \choose 4}\cdot 6=90$ graphs with two triangles.  By inclusion-exclusion there are $66 \cdot 20-90=1230$ graphs with triangles, so there are ${15 \choose 5}-1230=1773$ graphs without triangles.  The chance is then $\frac {1773}{3003} \approx 0.59$ that there is no triangle.

Comment: @bof:  Yes.  thanks

Comment: This is exactly as my solution.